# Wordpress setcookie() on splash page

Tags: php, wordpress, setcookie

I'm having a Wordpress website, and on main page, if visitor is here for the first time, a 'Subscribe to newsletter' modal appears. I'm having a problem that cookie is not being set via `setcookie()` function:

```
<?php 
            if($_COOKIE['rcngVisited'] != 'true')
            {
                echo do_shortcode('[modal name="Subscribe to newsletter" style=button color=default size=default][/modal]'); 
                setcookie('rcngVisited','true', time()+60*60*24*30, '/readyclickandgo/');
            }
        ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only set the cookie for `readyclickandgo` dir

Make sure you don't have any output before you set `COOKIE`, add this in your header:

```
<?php
    $visit = false;
    if($_COOKIE['rcngVisited'] != 'true'){
        setcookie('rcngVisited','true', time()+60*60*24*30, '/readyclickandgo/');
        $visit = true;
    }
?>
```

Add this anywhere you want in same page:

```
<?php
    if($visit){
        echo do_shortcode('[modal name="Subscribe to newsletter" style=button color=default size=default][/modal]'); 
    }
?>
```

Comment: This website is actually in subfolder `mydomain.com/readyclickandgo`, I also tried with `/`, but it's not working either.

Comment: Ok, you MUST setcookie before any text output.